# Using library functions that return arrays

Tags: mysql, c, pointers

This is a really novice question, but I don't write C unless (err, if) I can avoid it ;)

I've written a small extension to ruby that needed to interface with libmysql.  It works as expected, but now I'm in some doubt as to whether two lines of code a resulting in a possible memory leak.

Inside a tight loop I'm using functions `MYSQL_FIELD * mysql_fetch_fields( ... )` and `unsigned long * mysql_fetch_lengths( ... )`.

Since these functions *return* arrays, I assume they would use `malloc()` therefore require the user to call `free()` manually when finished with the result?  I expected this to be documented in the manual, but it's not, so I assume this is one of those things C developers just do instinctively: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-fields.html

Any pointers? (in the advice sense ;))

The code in question is here: https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus/blob/master/ext/oedipus/oedipus.c#L137-138

EDIT | Ugh, now I have a doubt.  It is documented to call `mysql_free_result()` on the result set, which was passed to `mysql_fetch_fields()`, so perhaps this is just returning a pointer to something that's already on the heap, from that MYSQL_RES struct.

EDIT 2 | Sorry for the noise.  It does appear that this information is just pulled from the `MYSQL_RES` struct which is an argument to `mysql_fetch_fields()`, and is itself freed later, so I'm probably fine:

```
typedef struct st_mysql_res {
  my_ulonglong  row_count;
  MYSQL_FIELD   *fields;
  MYSQL_DATA    *data;
  MYSQL_ROWS    *data_cursor;
  unsigned long *lengths;               /* column lengths of current row */
  MYSQL         *handle;                /* for unbuffered reads */
  const struct st_mysql_methods *methods;
  MYSQL_ROW     row;                    /* If unbuffered read */
  MYSQL_ROW     current_row;            /* buffer to current row */
  MEM_ROOT      field_alloc;
  unsigned int  field_count, current_field;
  my_bool       eof;                    /* Used by mysql_fetch_row */
  /* mysql_stmt_close() had to cancel this result */
  my_bool       unbuffered_fetch_cancelled;  
  void *extension;
} MYSQL_RES;
```

Comment: You don't write C unless you can avoid it? So you write C only when you can avoid it? :)

Comment: haha "if I can avoid it" or "unless I can't avoid it" would work in your case. If only English were as simple as C, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `mysql_free_result(result)` where result is the result of `mysql_fetch_fields`. C developers are used to this programming paradigm, but there is no one function you call to free something allocated in another library. Each library will have functions that allocate and return something, then a function to free the results of the allocation. The client can't free it itself with `free` or `delete` as it may be allocated on a different heap, and may be a complex object with multiple allocations inside.

Answer (score 1):

The API reference you've used so far provides the answer: You need to free the memory from result sets using the [`mysql_free_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-free-result.html) function:

> Frees the memory allocated for a result set by `mysql_store_result()`,
>   `mysql_use_result()`, `mysql_list_dbs()`, and so forth. When you are
>   done with a result set, you must free the memory it uses by calling
>   `mysql_free_result()`.
>
> Do not attempt to access a result set after freeing it.

And yes, C programmers are quite used to APIs that provide `_free()` routines for returned objects. It's just part of the territory.

Answer (score 1):

The function `mysql_store_result` store the whole result of the query in the heap, and returns a struct that contain pointers to all the data. Functions like `mysql_fetch_row` and `mysql_fetch_fields` just return some of this data. The function `mysql_free_result` is responsible to free the whole result data, including the fields `mysql_fetch_fields` returned.

So, you only need to call `mysql_free_result` after you use the data, and it will do the work.